# How to render GL_SHORT in java (endian)?

Tags: java, opengl, endianness, short

I am using `com.jogamp.opengl.GL2` to render a 3d-texture of shorts offscreen then resolve the results through `glReadPixels`. When my 3d-texture values are all positive, the results are what I expect. But when I have negative values I cannot figure out how to configure opengl to give correct results. I have tried `glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_PACK_SWAP_BYTES, 1);` and `glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, 1);`. I have tried all 4 combinations of GL_PACK/UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES and all results are incorrect.

The data spans from -1024 to +1024 (or around that range), so as an alternative, I normalize and denormalize after (+4096 then -4096 for good measure). That gives me the correct results, but it feels really hacky. Is there a correct way to render and resolve signed 16-bit through java?

Here is the basic code:

```
    private int upload3DTexture(GL2 gl2, ShortBuffer data) 
    {

        int texName[] = new int[1];
        gl2.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
        gl2.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
        gl2.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_PACK_SWAP_BYTES, 1);
        gl2.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, 1);
        gl2.glGenTextures(1, texName, 0);
        gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D);        
        gl2.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, texName[0]);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl2.glTexEnvi(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL2.GL_MODULATE);
        ((java.nio.Buffer)data).rewind();
        gl2.glTexImage3D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL2.GL_R16, nCols, nRows, nSlices, 0, GL2.GL_RED, GL.GL_SHORT, data);

        return texName[0];
    }

    private int upload3DTexture(GL2 gl2, ShortBuffer data) 
    {

        int texName[] = new int[1];
        gl2.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
        gl2.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
        gl2.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_PACK_SWAP_BYTES, 1);
        gl2.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, 1);
        gl2.glGenTextures(1, texName, 0);
        gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D);        
        gl2.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, texName[0]);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl2.glTexEnvi(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL2.GL_MODULATE);
        ((java.nio.Buffer)data).rewind();
        gl2.glTexImage3D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL2.GL_R16, nCols, nRows, nSlices, 0, GL2.GL_RED, GL.GL_SHORT, data);

        return texName[0];
    }


    private short[] renderAndResolve() {
        short[] volume= new short[64];
        short index = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    volume[index] = (short)(-100*z + y);
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        ShortBuffer shortBuffer = ShortBuffer.wrap(volume);
        texID = upload3DTexture(gl2, shortBuffer);

        display();
        ShortBuffer resultBuffer = ShortBuffer.allocate(nSlices * nRows);
        resolve(resultBuffer, 4, 4);
        return resolve.array();
    }

    private void resolveDisplay(ShortBuffer slice, int  w, int h)
    {
        GL2 gl2 = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); // The object that contains all the OpenGL methods.

        fbo.bind(gl2);
        gl2.glReadBuffer(GL2.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
        ((java.nio.Buffer)slice).rewind();
        int xd = (frameWidth  - w)/2;
        int yd = (frameHeight - h)/2;
        gl2.glReadPixels(xd, yd, w, h, GL2.GL_RED, GL2.GL_SHORT, slice);
        fbo.unbind(gl2);
        ((java.nio.Buffer)slice).rewind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is caused by the internal format of the texture.

> ```
> gl2.glTexImage3D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL2.GL_R16,
>                  nCols, nRows, nSlices, 0, GL2.GL_RED, GL.GL_SHORT, data);
> ```

The internal format `GL_R16` for the data store of a texture image is not a singed format, but it is an unsigned integral 16 bit format.

I don't know which OpenGL version you are using.

Desktop OpenGL provides the internal data format `GL_R16_SNORM` which is a 16 bit signed integral data format - see [`glTexImage3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage3D.xhtml).
[`GL_R16_SNORM`](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.0/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL2GL3.html#GL_R16_SNORM) is implemented in the interface [`GL2GL3`](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.0/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL2GL3.html):

```java
 gl2.glTexImage3D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL2GL3.GL_R16_SNORM,
                  nCols, nRows, nSlices, 0, GL2.GL_RED, GL.GL_SHORT, data);
```

OpenGL ES (3.0) provides an singed integral 8 bit format `GL_R8_SNORM`.
[`GL_R8_SNORM`](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.0/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL2ES3.html#GL_R8_SNORM) is implemented interface [`GL2ES3`](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.0/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL2ES3.html):

```java
 gl2.glTexImage3D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL2ES3.GL_R8_SNORM,
                  nCols, nRows, nSlices, 0, GL2.GL_RED, GL.GL_SHORT, data);
```

As an alternative both, desktop OpenGL and OpenGL ES, provide a 16 floating point format:

e.g.

```java
gl2.glTexImage3D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL2.GL_R16F,
                 nCols, nRows, nSlices, 0, GL2.GL_RED, GL.GL_SHORT, data);
```